# how to know the number clicked on the numeric keypad of the caller during a phone call (flutter, android or ios)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webrtc, call

We are in the process of developing a fluttering mobile application.
Here is what we need:
We receive a phone call in our application.
I pick up the incoming call.
The caller will click on number 5.
I wanted to know which number button was clicked by the caller during the incoming call.
Is there a way to detect which button the caller clicked in flutter, android or ios.
I appreciate any positive response.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API to do that in Android.  Possibly you could use the microphone to listen for the DTMF sound (the beep of the key on the line), but its unlikely to pick it up.  This just isn't supported.  Also in Android you can replace the default dialer, so even if the default one had an API for this, there's no way to assure a replacement does.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in the description, what I need is the same as voicemail. You can see it everywhere from voicemail services in companies. If we call a company, often there is an automatic answering machine which asks us for example to press the number 0 to speak with a receptionist and when we click on 0 the call goes to the receptionist. This is what I need, I want to know which button the caller clicked during the current call. I guess there is a way to do the same. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @MahdiAbdelmouleh Yeah, I understand what you need.  But voicemail doesn't run on Android devices, voicemail runs on servers in the cloud.  Those servers listen to the voice data stream for the DTMF tones.  There's no API to do this on an Android device.  And for security reasons you can't get a direct feed of the call voice data to do this yourself, even if you were willing to write some non-trivial audio processing algorithms.  You *might* be able to pick it up with the microphone, after which you might be able to detect the DTMF tones int he voice stream by audio processing.

Comment: But you'll have to roll it all by hand.  There isn't a built in API to say "He pressed 5" or even "He pressed a key".  The only part that does exist is detecting the incoming phone call itself.  Unless you own the phone line he's calling, then you can do it on that end.  But I'd look into existing solutions by large companies like Nuance Communications for that.